# Mass-remove movies from Netflix queue?

Tags: netflix

My wife and I tend to gradually accrue a huge list of movies in our Netflix queues, especially our Instant queue.  Eventually, despite removing movies as soon as we watch them, the remaining unwatched flotsam becomes annoying to page through (via the Xbox 360 or Wii clients) and tedious to fix (try manually removing 471 movies using netflix.com ...*ugh*).

Is there an easier way to declare “[queue bankruptcy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_bankruptcy)” and delete all movies from my Netflix instant queue?

Comment: See answer here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79677/quick-way-to-clean-up-netflix-viewing-activity-recently-watched-list/79678#79678

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>It depends on your technical capacity and amount of time that you're willing to invest. By the looks of it, netflix has a fairly rich api. So if you're willing to put the time in, you can probably script something up in a matter of a couple of hours (depending on ability...it might take only minutes if you're an expert, or days if not).</s> **Update:** [Netflix removed API support back in late 2014.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_details_of_Netflix#Netflix_API)

Alternatively, you can try out [this greasemonkey script to sort](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/35183) your queue - which, could allow you to vet out only *some* items. I hope this helps!

Comment: I actually did write an app to solve this problem not too long after asking this question.  The greasemonkey script is a much saner approach.  :)