# Quick way to clean up Netflix Viewing Activity (Recently Watched List)

Tags: netflix

If you've used Netflix a lot, you know how annoying it can be having a long list of "Viewing Activity", aka. stuff you've watched. In a normal browser, it's not so bad. However, as soon as you open it on your phone or a console, you quickly realize how short your choices become. All the simple, full categories like `Action` and `Anime` are quickly replaced with rows of `Because you watched ...`. The only way to do away with those rows, appears to be by going to your "Viewing Activity" and clicking delete next to everything you watch!
What's the quickest way to clean up this list?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution I've found has been to use a Google Chrome extension and a little, very simple JavaScript!

> Please Note: The following is a semi-permanent solution and will begin automatically cleaning your viewing history every time you visit the page. If that's not the solution for you, please skip to end!

First, if you don't already, get Google Chrome (<sub>Note: The extension I mention is available on FireFox as well</sub>). Then go to [Google Chrome Web](https://chrome.google.com/webstore) Store and add [`Custom JavaScript of websites (cjs)`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija?hl=en) to your Chrome extensions. This simple extension will allow you to run custom JavaScript on any website you visit, and includes use of jQuery!

<sub>The following is full instructions for getting to `Viewing Activity` page. Quick link button at end of paragraph, if it's not a dead link by the time you read this.</sub>
Now go to your [Netflix](https://www.netflix.com) account. Highlight your icon in upper right (your account name) and click on `Your Account` in the drop down that should appear. Scroll down to `My Profile` and click on [<kbd>Viewing Activity</kbd>](https://www.netflix.com/WiViewingActivity).

Now to make use of your new extension! First, *copy* the code below (at end) so you'll have it ready. Now, on your `Netflix Viewing Activity` page, open the `cjs` Chrome Extension. If you don't see it in your toolbar, look for a *`double right arrow`* at the end of your address bar. Click it to drop down your extensions. With `cjs` open, highlight and delete `placeholder` text. Paste in the code below, then click `Save`. The page will reload, and you'll immediately begin seeing action taking place.

*The one caveat* is that you have to scroll down to get all your viewing activity to show up. For this reason, and for the sake of not creating an overloading loop, you may have to reload the page a few times to get ALL your viewed movies/shows deleted from your history. I'm currently working on a better solution to that issue, but haven't really thought of one yet, and since mine is all cleaned up, I have little to test against! (which is a good thing, means this works great with semi-regular visits to the page).

The Codes:

```
function bob(){var a=jQuery(".deleteBtn:first");a.length&&setTimeout(function(){a.click();bob()},250)}
if(/viewingactivity/i.test(location)) bob();
```

---

> If you don't want to clean your viewing history every time you show up:

First, `Copy` the code above. Then go to your [<kbd>Viewing Activity</kbd>](https://www.netflix.com/WiViewingActivity) page. If the previous button doesn't work, simply go to your account page, look in `My Profile` section and click on `Viewing Activity`.

Now open your browsers developer tools. In most browsers this is as simple as pressing `F12`. Most Developer tools are divided into `tabs`. Make sure your in the `tab` that says and/or contains `Console`. There you can enter JavaScript manually. Now, before you enter any code, make sure your page is scrolled all the way to bottom. Netflix will `autoload` only so many rows at a time. In order to do this to your full viewing activity, you'll need to scroll until you reach the pages `footer`. Once your satisfied the list is full, simply `Paste` the code into the console and `run it`. For most browsers, that's as simple as pressing enter key, though some have a `Run` button to click on. Viola! You're done! Sit back and watch your history clean up!